# MySQL Regex - Having issues

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm having an issue with converting some regex to work with a MySQL query...

First of all, here is a http://www.regexr.com/ link... http://regexr.com/3c02t

As you can see it's working how I want. The 6812 is a user-supplied string, and I want to match all instances that end with a . and 3 numerical characters.

However, when I try to port this over to a MySQL query, I'm running into a brick wall. I'm try to do this query, and I'm not having any luck.

```
SELECT 
    id
FROM
    mytable 
WHERE
    summary REGEXP '^6812[.][0-9]{3}$' 
OR 
    detail REGEXP '^6812[.][0-9]{3}$'
```

I've looked around for the past hour and tried a bunch of different things, but I'm not having any luck here. Could someone possibly point me in the right direction on what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your regexp http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/25632  what is your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` and `$` are anchors they require the string be a full match. Specifically `^` is the start and `$` is the end.

In your provided example you aren't using these.

```
(6812)\.+[0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

that should actually be

```
(6812)\.[0-9]{3}([^0-9]|$)
```

So your example

```
Replace (24) 4569.000 with (24) 6812.000

blah blah blah 6812.000.
```

Should return true. We are checking after your value, a period, then 3 numbers and a non-number or the end of the string/column.

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/sK0nN5/1

Comment: Ah! I was misunderstanding the ^ and $ characters. Removing them worked!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes funny things may happen when you have a decimal number. Here's the suggestion.

```
create table test (id decimal(10,4));
insert into test values (6812.123), (6812.1234);

select * from test
where id regexp '^6812[.period.][0-9]{3}0*$'

Result:
6812.1230

select * from test
where id regexp '^6812[.period.][0-9]{3}$'

Result: nothing
```

The last query results in nothing is because `decimal(10,4)` results in 4 digit output after the decimal. So, `^6812.123$` is unmatched because the number actually is `6812.1230`

Therefore, if you are running in a situation like this, use a `0*$` to match zeros at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your problem is, but if you need to check only las 4 characters to match you can remove `^` symbol from your reg expression:

```
SELECT 
    id
FROM
    mytable 
WHERE
    summary REGEXP '\.[0-9]{3}$' 
OR 
    detail REGEXP '\.[0-9]{3}$'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/25641